# Store variables between ReactJs component method calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
togglePreloader: function(toggleState) {
    var timeout = null;
    var time = 0;
    if (toggleState) {
        if (this.state.preloading) console.log("Preloader alredy shown");
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
        } else if (!this.state.preloading) {
            console.log("Show preloader");
            time = Date.now();
            this.setState({ preloading: true });
        }
    } else {
        if (!timeout) {
            var elapsed = Date.now() - time;
            if (elapsed < Config.PRELOADER_MIN_DISPLAY_DURATION) {
                console.log("Preloader hiding timeout was started; elapsed: " + elapsed + "/" + Config.PRELOADER_MIN_DISPLAY_DURATION);
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    this.setState({ preloading: false });
                    console.log("Hide preloader by timeout");
                }.bind(this), Config.PRELOADER_MIN_DISPLAY_DURATION - elapsed);
            } else {
                this.setState({ preloading: false });
                console.log("Hide preloader; elapsed: " + elapsed + "/" + Config.PRELOADER_MIN_DISPLAY_DURATION);
            }
        } else console.log("Preloader hiding is waiting for timeout");
    }

}
```

This is the method of reactJs component. It trigger to show and hide preloader. If preloader was displayed less than minimal duration (e.g 500ms) it sets timeout on hiding.

The question is where to store variables **timeout** and **time** between calls of **togglePreloader**. Mutating **this.props** is not a good idea. Changes in **this.state** triggers rerendering. Moving variables out of component ? Or using state with **shouldComponentUpdate** ? What is the best way ? Im new to reactJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just not a good idea, you don't get to play with `this.props`, it's the collection of data that the component's parent controls. You can use state, which will render, or you can just do the obvious thing: just use `this.timeout = ...`, since your React component is still just a JavaScript object with its own instance scoping.

- `this.props.xyz` for values that you were assigned "from above"
- `this.state.xyz` for values that you control and directly influence what the UI should look like
- `this.xyz` for any transient values that have no influence on the UI and can technically be reset without any adverse effects.

However, consider that the timeout value is universal, so should probably be a static:

```
var YourComponent = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    timeout: 500
  },
  ...
  checkStuff: function() {
    if (this.currentTime >= YourComponent.timeout) {
      this.doAThing();
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

And if the idea is that different things happen to the UI based on that timeout, then *really* you should trigger some `state` value that your component can then use in `render()` to make sure it's now showing, or doing, the right thing. So you use a `this.currentTime` to track timing so far, and then a state variable once you *know* you've passed the threshold.

If you're new to react, it's 100% worth running through the "Getting started" and "tutorial" sections on the React website. Just sit down on them, do all of it in one go -it takes less than 30minutes- and you'll have a much better idea of how you're supposed to work with React. And then if you still need more insight, there are a *lot* of great articles on React on the googles.